# After logging in with Google it doesn't redirect me back to my app on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I got an `Ionic` + `Angular` + `Capacitor` app with Angular Fire Auth for the Google login. My app logs me in with Google on the Web version of it, but when I export it to an Android device the Google login doesn't redirects me back to the App it just stays in the phone browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here's the method for the Google login:

```
async loginClickGoogle() {
    try {
      const user = await this.authService.loginGoogle();
      //If the user exists
      console.log('User loginclickgoogle ->', user);
      if (user) {
        const isVerified = this.authService.isEmailVerified(user);
        if (isVerified) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('home');
          this.authService.getUID();
        } else {
          this.emailNotVerifiedToast();
        }
      } else {
        this.wrongUserLoginToast();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error', error);
      this.wrongUserLoginToast();
    }
  }
```

Here's the service method for the Google login:

```
async loginGoogle(): Promise<User> {
    try {
      const {user} = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
      this.userUID = user.uid;
      return user;
    }catch (error){
      console.log('Error-->',error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an android device you have to use GooglePlus plugin.
Docs here : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/google-plus/ngx';

constructor(private googlePlus: GooglePlus) { }

...

this.googlePlus.login({})
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```